# Integral Involving Square Roots

Tags: integration, arithmetic

Find the integral from 7 to 8 of $(x/(x-6))^(1/2)dx$

The questions hints that you should use that the integral of $1/(x^2-a^2)^1/2$ is equal to $ln(x+(x^2-a^2)^1/2) + C$

So I manipulated the integral to try to get something like that and I managed to get $(x^2+6x)^1/2/(x^2-36)^1/2$ by multiplying by the conjugate $(x^2+6)^1/2/(x^2+6)^1/2.$
Then I also completed the square:
$((x+3)^2-9)^1/2/(x^-36)^1/2$
Now I'm stuck..
Please help!

Answer (score 1):

If you are accustomed to hyperbolic functions, you could let $x=6\cosh^2 t$. Then $dx=12\cosh t\sinh t\,dt$, and $(x-6)^{1/2}=\sqrt{6}\sinh t$. We end up integrating a constant times $\cosh^2 t$.  This can be done in several ways, parts or a double "angle" identity.

Uglier is $x=6\sec^2 \theta$.

**Remark:** The following is equivalent to the $\cosh$ substitution, but less natural. Make the preliminary substitution $x=6t^2$. Our indefinite integral becomes
$$\int 12\frac{t^2}{\sqrt{t^2-1}}\,dt.$$
Rewrite the integrand as $12\sqrt{t^2-1}+12\frac{1}{\sqrt{t^2-1}}$.
For the second integral, make the "magic" substitution $w=\ln\left(t+\sqrt{t^2-1}\right)$. We get $dw=\frac{1}{\sqrt{t^2-1}}\,dt$. (!!) We leave the first integral to you.

Comment: OK, so using 6sec^2θ would you end up with the integral of 12sec^3θ/(6)^1/2 dθ?

Comment: I have added a remark to the post. It is basically the $\cosh$ substitution, but much closer in spirit to the hint you were given.

Comment: For the $\sec^2$ substitution, yes. That's a pretty standard integral. But do try the one in the Remark. It is what your instructor intended. To me it is the $\cosh$ substitution, because the $\ln()$ is just the inverse of $\cosh$.